# Adding primary key plus Auto Increment to existing column

Tags: mysql

i want to ALTER a column of my table but its not working.

Showing error that

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 10000' at line 5

Here is the query:

```
ALTER TABLE employeeid

MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT (20)

PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Comment: ya the table is empty

Comment: `was about to type something simulare to Phil but his is good, use that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE employeeid MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT (20) Primary Key;

Alter Table employeeid auto_increment=10000;
```

Comment: When posting answers, please add and explanation describing what you changed or added or how it works or something. Even though your answer may be the solution, it's likely that some people who read this don't understand what it means or how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` seed value is a table option and as such, would need to be made separately for the table. You should also be able to add the primary key as a constraint instead of a column modification...

```
ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE employeeid
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (EMPID);
```

Answer (score 1):

As auto_increment is table related property so you need to do it separately on table:

```
ALTER TABLE employeeid MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT (20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE employeeid AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

You can also do it in single statement as per below:

```
ALTER TABLE employeeid MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT (20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire 2 separate queries as

```
ALTER TABLE employeeid MODIFY COLUMN EMPID INT (20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE employeeid AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Example : [**sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b58d6/1)